# Possible via DOM to retrieve axis header of td using header axis property directly?

Tags: html, dom, html-table

Something I've recently discovered is that I can set a table cell to have multiple axises using a combination of the `headers` property on the `td` and the `axis` property on any related `th`.  Example:

```
<table>
    <caption>Country Toy Codes</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col row"></th>
            <th scope="col" id="us" axis="country">US</th>
            <th scope="col" id="ca" axis="country">CA</th>
            <th scope="col" id="uk" axis="country">UK</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" id="robots" axis="toys">Robots</th>
            <td headers="us robots">ABC</td>
            <td headers="ca robots">DEF</td>
            <td headers="uk robots">GHI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" id="dolls" axis="toys">Dolls</th>
            <td headers="us dolls">JKL</td>
            <td headers="ca dolls">MNO</td>
            <td headers="uk dolls">PQR</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" id="slinkys" axis="toys">Slinkys</th>
            <td headers="us slinkys">STU</td>
            <td headers="ca slinkys">VWX</td>
            <td headers="uk slinkys">YZ1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" id="legos" axis="toys">Legos</th>
            <td headers="us legos">AB1</td>
            <td headers="ca legos">CD1</td>
            <td headers="uk legos">EF1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This has clear benefits for non-visual browsers, but I was thinking it could also be useful for javascript and css.  The only problem is that I'm not seeing a way to directly access the axis type of the header id of the cell, either after selecting or for selection purpose.

Ideally, I would like to do either of the following (rough pseduo-code ahead):

```
  Selector:
      td['axis=toys']  // Would select all td's with a header id that resolves to a header having axis value "toys"

  Getter:
      $('td').axisValue("toys") // would return the value, if applicable, of header id of header value with axis value of toys.
```

For the getter, I could loop through each header each time and find the element from the id in the DOM and then the axis value, but if there is a way to do this more directly, I'm sure it's also more optimized by the browser.

For the selector, the closest I can think of (in js) is to take the given axis value, find all ids using that axis value and then comma-separate each option to grab them all, such as

```
[headers~=us], [headers~=ca], [headers~=uk]
```

Does anyone know if header id's axis name is available either via a method or directly on the `td` element?

Comment: This is interesting. I wouldn't imagine the `td` contains any reference to the `th` in the DOM, since there's not even a direct descendant-ancestor relationship between the two, only at best a sibling relationship. You'd probably do best to write jQuery plugins for this sort of behavior.